# nested attributes paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Use paperclip for my images.

Models:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :regions
has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :country
has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => {
      :thumb=> "100x100>",
      :small  => "300x300>",
      :large => "600x600>"
        }   
end
```

My country index.html looks like this:

```
countries.each do |country| 
  country.name
```

I tried this:

```
link_to( image_tag(country.asset.image.url(:thumb)), country.asset.image.url(:original) )
```

But I get an error.

Someone ideas, what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got MANY assets for each country

```
countries.each do |country| 
  country.name
  country.assets.each do |asset|
    link_to( image_tag(asset.image.url(:thumb)), asset.image.url(:original) )
```

Or change it to `has_one` association